# Google cloud platform app deploy failure due to pyparsing

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pyparsing, python-packaging

I've successfully deployed many updates over the past weeks on google cloud platform, but I went to perform a standard deployment today and received this error:

found incompatible dependencies: "packaging 21.2 has requirement pyparsing<3,>=2.0.2, but you have pyparsing 3.0.5."

I tried installing different versions of pyparsing to resolve the issue but none worked with all other dependencies.  Are recent updates to pyparsing causing an issue?

Comment: There is a release of packaging coming out soon that is compatible with pyparsing 3.0.5. In the meantime, you can manually install pyparsing 2.4.7.

Comment: Thanks, version 2.4.7 did work.  Appreciate it!

Comment: Pyparsing 3.0.6 added code that should make it compatible with packaging, please try updating to pyparsing 3.0.6. If not successful, please post an issue on the pyparsing GitHub.

Comment: I just tried 3.0.6 for the fun of it, and it does not work.

Comment: Please post an issue to GitHub, with any error messages that might help isolate the problem.

Comment: I did a couple hours ago.

Comment: Is it this one? https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/issues/337  Can you provide a little more information on what exactly doesn't work? An error message? The requirement that is failing to parse? 3.0.6 passes all the current packaging unit tests, and fails one 21.2 unit test with a cosmetic error (changed exception message). I'm happy to look further into this, but I need more to go on.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239176/discussion-between-paulmcg-and-sarco).

Answer (score 0):

Pyparsing versions compatible with packing 21.2 are versions <3 and > 2.0.2.
you can install 2.4.7 which is the immediate version [before version 3.](https://pypi.org/project/packaging/#history)

You can install 2.4.7 by using command **pip install pyparsing=2.4.7**

Comment: Pyparsing 3.0.6 (just released) should resolve this incompatibility with packaging.